# Можно ли начинать предложение с личного местоимения "я"?

Tags: синтаксис, местоимения

Можно ли начинать предложение с личного местоимения "я"?

Comment: Екатерину поставило в тупик уверждение, что с "я" предложения начинать нельзя. Якобы, еще в школе этому учат. (Например, вместо "Я служил в пограничных войсках" нужно писать "Служил в пограничных войсках").

Answer (score 3):

Сколько угодно!

> "Я памятник себе воздвиг чудесный, вечный..."
>
> "Я памятник себе воздвиг нерукотворный..."
>
> "Я помню чудное мгновенье..."
>
> "Я достаю из широких штанин..."
>
> "Я спросил сегодня у менялы..."
>
> "Я обманывать себя не стану..."
>
> "Я пригласил вас, господа, с тем, чтобы сообщить вам пренеприятное известие: к нам едет ревизор".

Comment: Я считаю, что во всех примерах (это неполные цитаты) необходимо поставить в конце троеточие (кроме последнего).

Answer (score 1):

Можно ли начинать предложение с личного местоимения "я"? Конечно, можно! Примеры даже стыдно приводить. Откройте любую книжку. Вспомните любую песню.

Есть случаи, когда стилистически лучше опустить *я*. Но это не то же самое что "с *я* предложения начинать нельзя".

Answer (score 1):

(Попытаюсь ответить, хотя не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос.)

**Можно ли начинать предложение с личного местоимения "я"?**

Смотря какое предложение. Например, предложение "Я отвечаю на вопрос" — можно. А вот предложение "Во поле берёзка стояла" — нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Сама филолог, но вот таким утверждением меня на работе поставили в тупик. Поэтому решила найти ответ